# Highcharts not initiating in modal

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, modal-dialog

I have a basic highchart that I display in a modal. it appears to render in the base html but won't display once the modal is displayed (unless I tell the browser to do something like just resize the window or redraw by enacting a plugin).
Not sure if this is a DOM thing or a js thing honestly. It's the same in Firefox, Chrome and Safari mac.
Is there something simple that can 'goose' the window on click or ??
I'm using bootstrap js standard modal code

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you provide relevant site or even better - a jsfiddle.

Comment: I have it on a modal and it works well.

Comment: http://creamycenterlabs.com/reports.html 
It's the green button
(didn't initially include this because the code is literally just a copy/paste from highcharts and bootstrap demos)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Charts cannot be initialized in hidden div, so You can open modal, then run i.e setInterval() function with small time and then create chart.

EDIT:
Take look at solution which can help you to display chart in hidden modal div.
http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue with Highcharts and Bootstrap's Carousel. To workaround it, I show the element before drawing into it with Highcharts, then I hide it after.

https://github.com/rootux/angular-highcharts-directive/issues/1